# How to optimize the given algorithm by reordering the instructions

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I know that the following pseudocode can be optimized by changing the order of the instructions, but I don't know how to go about it.
The algorithm performs operations on a matrix that is a multidimensional array.

**m** is the height of this array (int)

**n** is the width of this array (int)

**tab** is that array given as a function parameter

```
function coto(m, n, tab){
    for(i:=0; i<n; i:=i+2){
        if(n==m){
            tab[i][i]:=i-3
        }
    }
    
    for(j:=m-1; j>0; j:=j-1){
        tab[j-1][j]:=j+2
        tab[j][j]:= -tab[j][j]
    }
    
    return tab
}
```

example input for that function:

```
 
coto(4,4,|2, 2, 2, 2|)
         |2, 2, 2, 2|
         |2, 2, 2, 2|
         |2, 2, 2, 2|

#and output I got:
                  |-3, 3, 2, 2|
                  |2, -2, 4, 2|
                  |2,  2, 1, 5|
                  |2,  2, 2,-2|
```

Didnt know how to include latex in this question so tried my best.

I dont know what should I do. I cant get instruction outsite if or for bcs it doesnt make sense in my opinion.

Comment: the first for-loop only executes something useful if `m==n`, so you can bring the if-statment outside (`if (m == n) { for(i:=0; i<n; i:=i+2) { tab[i][i] = i-3 } }`

Comment: The code, on the other hand, could be correct, but it looks ... mysterious. Are you sure this is what should be coded?

Comment: @kvantour yes, this is it. Thank you. You can write this as answer so Ill mark that as best answer.

Comment: @kvantour and this code is 100% correct. It doesn't do anything special, it's a task I found on the internet to optimize it but I couldn't figure out how to do it and it was bothering me. However, the solution is trivial :D

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the possibility chances as two ways.
The first is `n==m` and the second is `n!=m`.

I think this code will be more faster than yours.

```
function coto(m, n, tab){
    if(m==0) return
    if(n==m){
        tab[0][0]:=-3
        for(i:=2; i<n; i:=i+2){
            tab[i][i]:=3-i
            tab[i-1][i-1]:=-tab[i-1][i-1]
            tab[i-2][i-1]:=i+1
            tab[i-1][i]:=i+2
        }
        if(n%2==0){
            tab[n-1][n-1]:=tab[n-1][n-1]
            tab[n-2][n-1]:=n+1
        }
    } else {
        for(j:=m-1; j>0; j:=j-1){
            tab[j-1][j]:=j+2
            tab[j][j]:=-tab[j][j]
        }
    }
}
```

And in my experience it's faster to call the variables from one dimensional array than two dimensional array.

So we can declare `a[j]:=tab[j][j]` and `b[j]:=tab[j-1][j]`, then change all `tab` to `a` and `b`.